# How to convert a group row header into column cell value?

Tags: excel

I have data that is grouped as shown in image1

I want convert the grouped rows headers into column cell values as shown in image2

Any way to do it in Excel, or in R?

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

Comment: R and Excel are very different tools.  You should tell us which one you are really using here.

Comment: I am hoping to get it done in Excel but if thats complex, R would be fine assuming its not too much R code..

Comment: Please share sample data using `dput` and the expected output